# Redirect link from http to https for main homepage domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How do I write redirect link from http to https for main homepage domain only?

```
Redirect example.com https://example.com
Redirect http://example.com https://example.com
Redirect http://www.example.com https://example.com
Redirect www.example.com https://example.com
```

Which is the correct one to add in .htacess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to redirect HTTP to HTTPS

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```